# Training separate models for sets of features?

Tags: feature-selection, ensemble-learning, stacking

I'm wondering if it is sensible to train different models for different sets of features (I do not mean one model for each feature).

Say I have 4 features - 2 are nominal while the other two are 2 continuous.

Does it make sense to train a model on 2 nominal attributes to make a prediction and another model based on the remaining 2 attributes? In the end one can ensemble the results (say by voting).

What I'm suggesting is a sort of vertical stacking. Is this a valid method? If yes, is there a formal term for it so I can read up more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, depending on the method.  What you are describing above is part of how a Random Forest (a type of ensemble) works.  Each tree in the forest is trained using only a subset of the features (see the `mtry` argument in R's `randomForest` package, for example).  In a Random Forest, each decision tree is also trained on a subsample of the training set, which adds additional randomness, and contributes to added diversity among the base models (trees) in the ensemble.

Using a subset of features for each constituent model of the ensemble can also be helpful in [stacking](http://learn.h2o.ai/content/tutorials/ensembles-stacking/).